# How can I connect geth by IPC on rails?

Tags: go-ethereum, ipc, bug, ruby, rails

I'd like to connect geth by IPC on rails. I start geth as follows.

```
$build/bin/geth --datadir "/home/vagrant/.ethereum" --networkid "1" --ipcapi "admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3" --ipcpath "/home/vagrant/.ethereum/geth.ipc"
```

Then I tried to connect from `rails console` using [ethereum-ruby](https://github.com/DigixGlobal/ethereum-ruby).  However, it returns error. Could you tell me how to connect geth from ruby?(It doesn't matter whether it is used the [library](https://github.com/DigixGlobal/ethereum-ruby) or not.

```
[1] pry(main)> client = Ethereum::IpcClient.new("#{ENV['HOME']}/.ethereum/geth.ipc")
=> #<Ethereum::IpcClient:0x007f4f4365f470
 @batch=[],
 @id=1,
 @ipcpath="/home/vagrant/.ethereum/geth.ipc">
[2] pry(main)> client.eth_coinbase
NoMethodError: undefined method `eth_coinbase' for #<Ethereum::IpcClient:0x007f4f4365f470>
from (pry):2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I can reproduce this, it's either a bug or a lack of documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong command, the command is `coinbase`, not `eth_coinbase`.

I suggest to use this code:

```
eth = Ethereum::IpcClient.new
```

This will automatically use the default path to get `geth.ipc`

```
puts eth.coinbase["result"]
```

And this will return your coinbase.

You can see that [this line](https://github.com/DigixGlobal/ethereum-ruby/blob/ebec75a0515139ddb6aa0bb712429334ae7ae01d/lib/ethereum/ipc_client.rb#L13), used to create the new method, is not getting the first part of the rpc method name, and, it's underscoring the method, so `eth_coinbase` will be `coinbase`, `eth_getBalance` will be `get_balance` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the new `eth` gem, you would have to create an IPC client:

```ruby
ipc = Eth::Client.create "/home/vagrant/.ethereum/geth.ipc"
ipc.eth_coinbase # or: ipc.default_account
```

See: https://github.com/q9f/eth.rb/wiki/RPC-Client