# Ethereum and Rails Tutorials

Tags: ruby, rails

I am looking for some kind of walk through or tutorial about how to use ethereum with an ruby on rails application?

Is there anything out there?

Answer (score 4):

You can find so many tools for using ruby to access the Ethereum Blockchain.

You have for example (like [5chdn♦](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/87/5chdn) said in a comment):

- [ethereum-ruby](https://github.com/DigixGlobal/ethereum-ruby) made by [DigixGlobal](https://digix.io/#/).
- [ruby-ethereum](https://github.com/janx/ruby-ethereum) made by [janx](https://github.com/janx).
- [rails-eth-api](https://github.com/rexmadden/rails_eth_api) made by [rexmadden](https://github.com/rexmadden).

Also, here you have an Ethereum StackExchange answer which tells about [how to connect Geth by IPC on rails](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1552/how-can-i-connect-geth-by-ipc-on-rails).

Comment: this are certainly some useful links, but not really a tutorial on how to create a frontend / sql & eth backend symbiosed application. I have questions like: Where and how to host your geth client, how to read/write from/to it with a controller and how to present data in the view(and/or send input fields data to geth). Is it secure or is it practical at all? etc....

Comment: If you know about js, Truffle is what you are looking for

Comment: I know js, but I'm more familiar to write in a conventional db with rails. Is truffle for frameworks like Meteor / AngualrJS / backbone etc? or is it compatible with rails?

Comment: I think Truffle is a framework. It runs in node btw

Answer (score 2):

You can check also [ethereum.rb](https://github.com/marekkirejczyk/ethereum.rb).

It is more recent ruby gem, supporting parity 1.5+ and solidity compiler. 
It comes with:

- [video introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Swb-QnX2X_U&t=856s) to smart contracts
- step by step usage guide in readme

Comment: Might be a useful tutorial too https://chainstack.com/deploying-an-ethereum-smart-contract-with-eth-ruby-gem/

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [ethereum-tx](https://github.com/se3000/ethereum-tx) gem. It is intended for keeping the signing and building of transactions separate from the full node. You could host your full node on the same server, but you don't need to. For a lot of Ethereum applications, you only need to be able to read the blockchain and send transactions. Depending on the frequency with which you need to do this, you could run your own node, or maybe get away with using a [block explorer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/404/what-ethereum-blockchain-explorers-exist)'s API.

If you already have private keys with ether you can import them, or generate new keys to send Ethereum(see `Ethereum::Key` class). Once you have some keys you can build transactions and sign them with the key(see `Ethereum::Tx` class). Finally, you can encode those transactions and broadcast them to an Ethereum full node using the [JSON-RPC API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendrawtransaction), or any [block explorer](https://etherscan.io/pushTx) that supports raw transactions(either way you just need an [HTTP library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)).

The one thing left to do is get notifications about when an address receives messages or ether. [Events](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI#events) work for contracts, but not regular accounts. I'm not really sure of a fully comprehensive solution in any language, so I'd recommend rolling your own based on your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

I have published an [*Ethereum on Rails*](https://github.com/q9f/ethereum-on-rails) template on Github.

It is a boilerplate application that allows authenticating users in your Rails 7.0 application with an Ethereum wallet (e.g., MetaMask).

[image: Screenshot of the Demo]

You can use this repository as a template to create your custom Rails application that already has Ethereum support bundled. It uses the new [`eth`](https://github.com/q9f/eth.rb) gem for Ethereum account management.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/fogonthedowns/blupee is a simple Ruby interface for working with the Ethereum Blockchain:

new wallet:

```
ether_wallet = Blupee::API::Ether.new_wallet('[hidden]')
```

wallet balance:

```
ether_balance = Blupee::API::Ether.balance("0xad96B1072E60f6279F628E7512242F9b1A83127F")
```

erc20 tokens:

```
args = {wallet_address:"", contract_address:""}
Blupee::API::Token.balance(args)
```