# How can I connect my Rails app to an ethereum network?

Tags: solidity, testrpc, ruby, rails

At this time I'm just trying to setup the simplest of apps where I click a button and that will send the most basic of transactions to my testrpc network. It's easy to do with JS and web3, but how can I do this with Ruby on Rails ?

Comment: There are a few ruby ethereum libraries. See this question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2812/ethereum-and-rails-tutorials

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to connect Rails with Ethereum,

I recently used

- [coinfalcon](https://docs.coinfalcon.com) for Python and Ruby. This provides API for placing orders with the help of this.
- [Ethereum Ruby](https://github.com/q9f/eth.rb) This helps you connect with Ethereum.

Here you can do:

1. IPC Client Connection
2. Solidity contract compilation and deployment
3. Transacting and Calling Solidity Functions

Answer (score 1):

I have published an [*Ethereum on Rails*](https://github.com/q9f/ethereum-on-rails) template.

It is a boilerplate application that allows authenticating users in your Rails 7.0 application with an Ethereum wallet (e.g., MetaMask).

You can use this repository as a template to create your custom Rails application that already has Ethereum support bundled. For example, it uses the new [`eth`](https://github.com/q9f/eth.rb) gem for Ethereum account management.

If you already know how to use Rails, you can utilize the following functionality of the `eth` gem:

```ruby
test_rpc = Eth::Client.create "http://127.0.0.1:8545"
some_trx = Eth::Tx.new {
  chain_id: test_rpc.chain_id,
  nonce: test_rpc.get_nonce test_rpc.default_account,
  priority_fee: 1 * Eth::Unit::GWEI,
  max_gas_fee: 23 * Eth::Unit::GWEI,
  gas_limit: Eth::Tx.estimate_intrinsic_gas,
  to: Eth::Address.new "0xCaA29806044A08E533963b2e573C1230A2cd9a2d",
  value: 1 * Eth::Unit::ETHER,
}
```

And then you can sign and broadcast it, see: https://github.com/q9f/eth.rb/wiki/Transactions

Or simply run:

```ruby
test_rpc.transfer Eth::Address.new("0xCaA29806044A08E533963b2e573C1230A2cd9a2d"), 1 * Eth::Unit::ETHER
```

See https://github.com/q9f/eth.rb/wiki/RPC-Client