# How to execute smart-contract functions on Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to execute smart-contract functions using Ruby?
For example executing function mint on behalf of the smart-contract's owner?

Comment: This tutorial covers executing a smart contract function too using the eth.rb gem https://chainstack.com/deploying-an-ethereum-smart-contract-with-eth-ruby-gem/

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any reason why you couldn't use Ruby to interact with Ethereum, after all it's possible to interact with an Ethereum node over RPC calls.

You might find this [other Ruby question and its answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2813/8469) useful.

There are some other links on [ethdocs for projects looking at using Ruby with Ethereum](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/ruby-ethereum/).