# Ruby library for Ethereum

Tags: ruby

What is the well accepted and active Ruby library for Ethereum? This [article](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2812/ethereum-and-rails-tutorials)  lists quite a few libraries but none of them seems to be actively maintained. I am looking for an `Ruby` library for my Ethereum `Dapp` with `Ruby on Rails` as web framework and `MetaMaks` as browser extension.

Comment: Do the links from this answer work for you https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/2813/?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclosure: I'm the maintainer of the following libraries.*

- [Ethereum on Rails](https://github.com/q9f/ethereum-on-rails): Connect your Rails 7.0 application to Metamask.
- [q9f/eth.rb](https://github.com/q9f/eth.rb): A rewrite and merge of all previously existing Ruby gems.

As of February 2022 - I hope this is helpful for users looking for that answer too.

Comment: Just to add, an eth.rb tutorial that might be useful https://chainstack.com/deploying-an-ethereum-smart-contract-with-eth-ruby-gem/